# DBML generated code get duplicate keys Value and Value1

Tags: linq, foreign-keys, duplicates

When i generate the LINQ model from the folowing table:

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    Id        INT            IDENTITY,
    Value     VARCHAR(10)    REFERENCES Value(Id),

    PRIMARY KEY(Id)
)
GO
```

I get an auto generated class like this:

```
class Test
{
    Id
    Value
    Value1
}
```

Anyone got any ideas on why the second Value "Value1" is added.

BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved!**

Implement the table like this and it will work (You will get Value and Value_FK).

```
CREATE TABLE Test
(
    Id           INT            IDENTITY,
    Value_FK     VARCHAR(10)    REFERENCES Value(Id),

    PRIMARY KEY(Id)
)
GO
```

And you will get:

```
class Test
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Value_FK { get; set; }
    Value Value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Value1` refers to the `Value` reference property on your Test class.

The class has a `varchar(10)` which is named `Value`, but it also has a reference to another table called `Value`.

It can't have two properties with the same name, so one is renamed to `Value1`